# Repeat a process for several .csv files (containing points) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, point, loop, extract

I need to extract the time series of estimated NDWI from LANDSAT for three year (2020-2022) all around the word. I have to do this process over a regular grid (9-km) and I noticed that the process works for a maximum number of point. Actually, there is a point number limitation. Hence, I divided my grid points in to several .csv files. I import all files into GEE coding environment and I have to call one of them each time and extract the values for them and save the value as a .csv file.

I am looking for a way to write a loop to hand this process. Actually, I need a `for` loop to call the imported files in the programming environment of GEE and do the process for them separately. For example, I import two .csv files in the following code (`point1` and `point2`) and I need that the code be run two times using `for` loop.

How can I do this? I have to say that in reality I have much more files.

```
var point1: Table users/...
var point2: Table users/...

var LS8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA');

///the repeated part 
var FieldLS8 = LS8.filterBounds(point1).filterDate('2020-01-01', '2022-12-31').sort('CLOUD_COVER')

var cloudlessNDVI_LS8 = FieldLS8.map(function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var mask = cloud.lte(50);
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).updateMask(mask);
});

var poiArray = cloudlessNDVI_LS8.select('NDWI').getRegion(point1, 30);

var names = poiArray.get(0)
var values = poiArray.slice(1)

var exportFC = ee.FeatureCollection(
  values.map(function(values){
    return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(names, ee.List(values)))
  })
)

var sortedFC = exportFC.sort('id')

print(sortedFC)

Export.table.toDrive(sortedFC)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by:

1. Wrap your process in a function that acts on an assetId

```js
function myProcess(assetId){
 // your code here loads the table 
// e.g., 
// var table = ee.FeatureCollection(assetId).
// then processes it and creates the Export.table.toDrive task. 
}
```

2. Get the list of assetIds using [ee.data.listAssets](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-listassets):

```js
var files = ee.data.listAssets("path/to/your/project/asset/folder")
```

This returns an object with an `assets` List.

3. You can do a (client-side) `map` on that list:

```js
files.assets.map(myProcess)
```

However, note that each element in the `assets` list contains four fields: `type`, `id`, `name`, and `updateTime`. So we should modify the `myProcess` so that it retrieves the id from this object:

```js
function myProcess(assetObject){
// var table = ee.FeatureCollection(assetObject.id)
```

Now you just need to make sure that the folder only contains the csv files that you want to process.

Note that the export tasks will be created, but not started. So you will have to manually start them (click on "Run") on the Tasks panel. If you are comfortable porting your process to python, then it will be straightforward to automate starting the tasks.

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thanks for your reply. I correct the code in the following way. However, when I run the code I face with an error in the second line of code:cannot use 'in' operator to search for "type" in "users/miiinarasu

Comment: Here is the link:https://code.earthengine.google.com/add314f496c594f7980666b7d82a1c53

Comment: In your last line, instead of `myProcess(assetIds)`, you want to do `assetIds.map(myProcess)` . That is, your `myProcess` function operates on each element of `assetIds` at a time. Currently, you are trying to pass the entire `assetIds` (a list) as an argument to `myProcess` function, which fails because it is expecting a single id, not a list.